# Deeplinking Interactive Post in Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying out the interactive post from Google plus sample project.

```
private Intent getInteractivePostIntent() 
{
    String action = "/?view=true";
    Uri callToActionUrl = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url) + action);
    String callToActionDeepLinkId = getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id) + action;


    PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
    builder.addCallToAction(LABEL_VIEW_ITEM, callToActionUrl, callToActionDeepLinkId);
    builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_url)));
    builder.setContentDeepLinkId(getString(R.string.plus_example_deep_link_id),
            null, null, null);
    builder.setText(getString(R.string.inviteText));

    builder.setRecipients(recipients);

    return builder.getIntent();
 }
```

Accourding to doc:

```
 plus_example_deep_link_url: is for desktop
 plus_example_deep_link_id: is for mobile
```

So I was trying out the link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkleft.eightyeightsms.mms

```
 <string name="plus_example_deep_link_url">https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkleft.eightyeightsms.mms</string>
<string name="plus_example_deep_link_id">com.abc.cdef</string>
```

What should I enter in deep_link_id? The results come up even if I enter a random text there?

Comment: The first Google result for "deep link Google+" has an entire page on exactly this question: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link#2_choosing_a_deep-link_identifier

Comment: @abraham: I have seen the link the problem is that I didn't understand what they are explaining for deep_link_id? Hence posted a question in SO if somebody can explain on this?

Comment: There is an entire section on it but to keep it simple just use the same URL a user would use to visit the page in a browser.